# Tapestry component cache

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, tapestry

I have a component in my web application (the menu) that is rendered for every page, and it's useless and takes up resources.

Is there a way to put a cache on this component, so that its HTML output is cached?

Note: I already use EhCache, maybe there's a way to interface them?

Comment: How long can it take to render a menu? Have you measured? Are you caching the data used in the menu already (I suspect you do heavy IO in there)?

Comment: @Henning: all the data for the menu is cached, there are just too many cache accesses, this is the reason I'm looking to cache this static component.

Comment: Fair enough. So the cache is the new bottleneck? I like that.

Comment: @Henning: I'd rather say that's the code in the component, quite complex and calling the cache a lot of times.

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for created a [Tapestry cache](http://tapestry.ioko.com/)  extension to do this. I haven't used in a while, but we used it on some quite big sites in the last few years and gave us some good results.

Comment: Hi, this is very interesting, however I'm looking for a project more viable, if I can say. I don't think my company would want to use this component if that was only the work of one company, without having any guarantee (a wide scale active open-source project with different contributors would be better). Not against you or your company.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at :

[IOKO cache](http://tapestry.ioko.com/tapestry-caching/index.html)

Looks nice, even if I wished more flexibility to the cache names which are stuck to an Enum (CacheRegion)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your component does some database access or other heavy work, there's no point in caching it; it would just be premature optimizations. Further, its best to cache the data used by the component, rather than attempting to cache the output of the component.

Comment: Well, that's a great way to get help!  Post your performance analysis. Numbers are all that count, intuitions are usually way, way off.

Comment: Why do you need my performance analysis??? I know them, that's enough for me, I don't want you to analyze them thank you... I'm not talking about intuitions here!! Do you understand that I know what I'm doing, and I don't need/want to know your feeling about it. **I just posted a simple question, and I just looking for an answer to that question...** If you don't have one, that's fine just leave this thread.

Comment: Sometimes, it feels like people need to be quizzed on http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html before they should be allowed to post :-)

Comment: I'm sorry if your answer is plain wrong: my component does heavy work, there's a point in caching it, that's not premature optimization, the data used by the component is already cached... Now check your answer, you'll see that every sentence you made (using assumptions) is wrong. This is the reason why I posted that I was looking for a way to put a cache, not a solution to my performance problem, that's different.

Answer (score 0):

If this app is under extreme load you might want to consider using **[edge side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes)**. With a caching proxy such as [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/) you can then cache fragments of a page so that you won't have to regenerate those parts of the page on each request. There's a good explanation of the process in [this article](http://cd34.com/blog/scalability/wordpress-varnish-and-esi-plugin/).